# how to change default subtitle in MKV file (the file has multiple subtitle) with windows media player?

Tags: video

I've downloaded a video in MKV format, the file has more than one subtitle (french, english,etc ) but the default subtitle isn't english.

how to change the default subtitle to english in windows media player ?

Answer (score 0):

Rename English subtible file to the same name of video file (of course keep its extension). I watch film quite often and that's is the way I alway do.